# When programming an Arduino in C, how do we write two characters next to each other?

Tags: arduino, lcd, adafruit, arduino-c++

I have the following code for my arduino, however the adafruit  lcd display only prints the down arrow character and not the up arrow then the down arrow. (the loop function is empty so I didn't include it).

```cpp
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_RGBLCDShield.h>
#include <utility/Adafruit_MCP23017.h>
Adafruit_RGBLCDShield lcd = Adafruit_RGBLCDShield();

#define UP_ARROW 0
byte up[] = {4, 14, 31, 4, 4, 4, 0, 0};
#define DOWN_ARROW 1
byte down[] = {0, 0, 4, 4, 4, 31, 14, 4};

void setup() {
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.begin(16,2);
  lcd.setCursor(0,0);
  lcd.createChar(UP_ARROW, up);
  lcd.write(UP_ARROW);
  lcd.setCursor(1,0);
  lcd.createChar(DOWN_ARROW, down);
  lcd.write(DOWN_ARROW);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my problem is that creating a character resets the cursor position to (0,0), so when I set the cursor to (0,1) and create the down arrow, it resets the cursor to (0,0). My solution was to create the custom characters first and then set the cursor and write them.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your library's source code,

```
void Adafruit_RGBLCDShield::createChar(uint8_t location, uint8_t charmap[]) {
  location &= 0x7; // we only have 8 locations 0-7
  command(LCD_SETCGRAMADDR | (location << 3));
  for (int i=0; i<8; i++) {
    write(charmap[i]);
  }
  command(LCD_SETDDRAMADDR);  // unfortunately resets the location to 0,0
}
```

If I were you I would create the characters at the start of the program, then position the cursor and write them as needed.

Answer (score 0):

From the  [Arduino reference](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/LiquidCrystalCreateChar):

> NB : When referencing custom character "0", if it is not in a variable, you need to cast it as a byte, otherwise the compiler throws an error. See the example below.

In your example, `UP_ARROW` will be replaced be `0` in `lcd.write(UP_ARROW);`

Maybe try: `lcd.write(byte(UP_ARROW));`

Hope it helps.